# Dependencies To Make Python Script Executable

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, executable, cx-freeze

I wrote a python program on Ubuntu(machine 1), working well. 
I want to make it executable on machine 2(Fresh Ubuntu Installed) by using `cxfreeze`.

I run following commands on machine 2 terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install cxfreeze
cxfreeze pythonfile.py
```

After these command, when I try to run executable file, its Not working.
Not Working: means `no error, no action and no message`
It is my first experience, so want to know what steps I have to take before make it executable on different Ubuntu machine.

Comment: what is the content of your python script?

Comment: @Martin `tkinter, subprocess,datetime, tkSimpleDialog, paramiko, os, re`

Comment: "its Not working" - in what way? Do you seen an error message? What happens? We can't help if you don't give details of what the problem is.

Comment: @ThomasK there is no error message... it seems like nothing when I clicked on executable file

Comment: Try running it from a command prompt - there might be an error message that disappears before you see it.

Comment: how do i run it from command terminal.. means need to write or any specific syntax

Comment: Does your script read from stdin, and is there anything connected to stdin? When you say "no action," do you get a shell prompt back?

Comment: yup i m using stdin... but nothing prompt back